# Is "gata" vulgar? What about "gatita"?

Tags: sustantivos

It's been indicated to me that in French "la chatte" (feminine version of "le chat", *the cat*) is used as a vulgar term and its usage is somewhat delicate.

Does the same apply to *gata*, or *gatita*?

Comment: [Gata fiera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZVLmlwVAZc) and [Gata bajo la lluvia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69bcTk0K2Rs), could be offensive in many cases, but also a compliment, according to the place and the context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Gato", and its feminine form "gata", are the normal way of referring to animals of the **Felis silvestris catus** subspecies.

"Gatita" is a normal way of referring to one's female cat, or any other female cat to which one has sentimental attachment.

On the other hand, the same words "gata" and "gatita" can be used to refer to a woman. This second usage is, at least, familiar, and may be deemed vulgar or offensive depending on the context.

Comment: [Gata fiera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZVLmlwVAZc)  and [Gata bajo la lluvia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69bcTk0K2Rs), could be offensive in many cases, but also a compliment, according to the place and the context

Answer (score 1):

I am from México and "gato" and "gata" in reference to a person is very desrespectful:

1. No soy tu gato. I am not your servant, worker, maid or something like that.

"Gato" y "gata" is used to talk about poor people. And "Gata" and "Gatita" are used as whore.

In argentina is the same meaning for memenine and masculine form